# Should we have a tag for kubernetes questions outside of a cloud environment?

Tags: discussion, tags

Essentially, the title. There are tags like [google-cloud-platform], [azure], and [amazon-web-services], but there isn't a tag [bare-metal]... well, OK, there is one, but it refers to something completely different: free-standing software, as opposed to hosted software.

If I have a question about kubernetes that is specific to a bare-metal installation, how should I highlight the fact that I am not using a cloud provider?

Comment: Just say so in the question?

Comment: So given a choice between a question which has only a kubernetes tag and a question which has a kubernetes AND a bare-metal tag, do you think that the bare-metal tag will increase the chance of people taking a look at your question? I can't imagine that it will.

Answer (score 3):

No, using Kubernetes outside of a cloud environment is a requirement. It doesn't take away from the fact that you're still using Kubernetes.

Add it as just a requirement in the question. If the question is otherwise properly tagged, the question will be found by experts who could help.